# How to callback user define function and display value

Tags: jquery

hello everyone i have one function that execute ajax request and result will return to another function but when i call that function it will return undefined value please help !

fu

```js
function getState(id)
{
    
    var StateJsonString = jQuery.parseJSON(id);
    var stateData;
    
    $.ajax({
        
        type: "POST",
        
        url: "phpFile/getStatenameVehiclePro.php",
       
        dataType: "json",
        
        data: { id:StateJsonString.state},
        
        success: function(stateFrom){
            
            stateData = stateFrom.data[0][1];
           
        },
        Fail: function(){
            
            alert("Cannot Loading State Name");
            
        },
        error: function(){
            
            alert("Cannot Loading State Name");
        }
        
    });
    
     return stateData;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Ajax`, A means `Asynchronous`. whats happening in your code is as soon as compiler reaches to your `ajax` function, it requests your `PHP` page and at same time. it returns `return stateData;` as well from the same function.

`var stateData;` is not assigned with any value. That is why it is returning `undefined` as your ajax call is started and browser does not wait for your ajax call to be completed first and it is executing in parallel serving `asynchronous` feature.

You must use `async: false` which is not recommended. But in your case this is working suggestion.

```
.ajax({            
        type: "POST",            
        url: "phpFile/getStatenameVehiclePro.php",           
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `async` option to false and return outside the ajax call.

- Setting `async to false` means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called.
- If you set `async: true` then that statement will begin it's execution and the next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet.

Example

```
function getState() {
    var result="";
    $.ajax({
      url:"URL",
      async: false,  
      success:function(data) {
         result = data; 
      }
   });
   return result;
}
```

**Additionally,**

Handle ajax request

```
//Ajax function call
function getState() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "URL"
  });
}

//Get ajax request
var promise = getState();

//Call on ajax success
promise.success(function (data) {
  //Do what you want
});
```